# Self.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Tags: ios, swift

Justing trying to add a bunch of objects.  What's wrong here? getting self.init isn't called on all paths?

```
    convenience init(testdata: Bool = false) {
    if testdata {
        let expenses = ["Housing", "Cell Phone", "Utilities", "Auto Insurance","Food", "Netflix","Internet"];
        let prices = [600,90,50,106,240,9,60];

        for i in 0..<6 {
            let expense = expenses[i];
            let valueInDollars = prices[i];
            self.init(expense: expense, valueInDollars: valueInDollars);
        }
    } else {
        self.init(expense: "", valueInDollars: 0);
    }
} <-- Error on this bracket
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that you can call `self.init` 6 times in an `init` method which is supposed to return **one** object.

Comment: Ah, ok. I hadn't realized it was one object init. Foolishness on my part